# onClick event of button not working android

Tags: android, button

I'm trying to implement Guillotine Menu by yalantis in my app.
I've put one button in the guillotine activity and have made a class for the guillotine activity. In that class I'm trying to implement the listener for the button .I've also a put a toast in that function but that's not getting displayed either.
Here is the guillotine activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/guillotine_background"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/guillotine_background"
            android:layout_margin = "0dp"
            android:divider="#666"
            android:orientation="vertical"   >
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        style="@style/Toolbar"
        app:contentInsetStart="0dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/guillotine_hamburger"
            style="@style/ImageView.Hamburger"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_menu" />
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/profile_group"
        style="@style/LinearLayout.GuillotineItem"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/guillotine_medium_margin">

        <ImageView
            style="@style/ImageView.GuillotineItem"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_profile" />

        <Button
            style="@style/TextView.GuillotineItem"
            android:text="MAIN PAGE"
           android:background="@color/guillotine_background"
            android:id="@+id/b1"
            />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/feed_group"
        style="@style/LinearLayout.GuillotineItem">

        <ImageView
            style="@style/ImageView.GuillotineItem"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_feed" />

        <TextView
            style="@style/TextView.GuillotineItem"
            android:text="@string/feed" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/activity_group"
        style="@style/LinearLayout.GuillotineItem">

        <ImageView
            style="@style/ImageView.GuillotineItem"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_activity_active" />

        <TextView
            style="@style/TextView.GuillotineItem.Selected"
            android:text="@string/activity" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/guillotine_divider_height" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/settings_group"
        style="@style/LinearLayout.GuillotineItem">

        <ImageView
            style="@style/ImageView.GuillotineItem"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_settings" />

        <TextView
            style="@style/TextView.GuillotineItem"
            android:text="@string/settings" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

And here is the class:

```
package manipal.freshers;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.File;

/**
 * Created by Ankit Vimal on 28-02-2016.
 */
public class Guillotine extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Button b1;
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.guillotine);
        b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.b1);
        b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                                  public void onClick(View v) {
                                      Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "a", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                                      Intent i = new Intent(Guillotine.this, MIT_Sports_Club_Activity.class);
                                      startActivity(i);


                                  }

                              }
        );
}

}
```

Styles.xml:

```
<resources>

    <style name="LinearLayout" />

    <style name="LinearLayout.GuillotineItem">
        <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:orientation">horizontal</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginTop">@dimen/guillotine_small_margin</item>
    </style>

    <style name="TextView" />

    <style name="TextView.ToolbarTitle">
        <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">24sp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    </style>

    <style name="TextView.GuillotineItem">
        <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginLeft">@dimen/guillotine_small_margin</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/guillotine_item_text_size</item>
        <item name="android:layout_gravity">center_vertical</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
    </style>

    <style name="TextView.GuillotineItem.Selected">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/selected_item_color</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Toolbar">
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
        <item name="android:minHeight">?attr/actionBarSize</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:background">@color/guillotine_background</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ImageView" />

    <style name="ImageView.ContentItem">
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ImageView.Hamburger" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ActionButton">
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginBottom">@dimen/abc_action_bar_overflow_padding_start_material</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ImageView.GuillotineItem">
        <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:layout_gravity">center_vertical</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginLeft">@dimen/guillotine_large_margin</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

Themes.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.Guillotine"/>

    <style name="Theme.Guillotine" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:color">@color/guillotine_background</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/guillotine_background</item>
        <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/guillotine_background_dark</item>
        <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

MainActivity.java:

```
package manipal.freshers;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;

import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.text.method.ScrollingMovementMethod;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;

import android.view.View;

import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import butterknife.ButterKnife;
import butterknife.InjectView;
import com.yalantis.guillotine.animation.GuillotineAnimation;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final long RIPPLE_DURATION = 250;
    @InjectView(R.id.toolbar)
    Toolbar toolbar;
    @InjectView(R.id.root)
    FrameLayout root;
    @InjectView(R.id.content_hamburger)
    View contentHamburger;

    private String[] drawerListViewItems;
    private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    private ListView drawerListView;
    private TextView t;
    int []imageArray={R.drawable.manipal1,R.drawable.manipal2,R.drawable.manipal3,R.drawable.manipal4,R.drawable.manipal5};
    private ImageView i1;
    private final Handler handler = new Handler();
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ButterKnife.inject(this);
        i1=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        t.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());

         if(toolbar!= null){
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11){
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle(null);
                    }}
        View guillotineMenu = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.guillotine, null);
        root.addView(guillotineMenu);

        new GuillotineAnimation.GuillotineBuilder(guillotineMenu, guillotineMenu.findViewById(R.id.guillotine_hamburger), contentHamburger)
                .setStartDelay(RIPPLE_DURATION)
                .setActionBarViewForAnimation(toolbar)
                .setClosedOnStart(true)
                .build();

        Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
            int i=0;
            public void run()
            {
                i1.setImageResource(imageArray[i]);
                i++;
                if(i>imageArray.length-1)
                {
                    i=0;
                }
                handler.postDelayed(this, 3000);  //for interval...
            }

        };
        handler.postDelayed(runnable,0);
    }

}
```

Comment: Are you getting nay exception, if your getting exception please post the stack trace.

Comment: can you please send me styles.xml file, i will try and post the answer

Comment: posted styles.xml and themes.xml

Comment: Rebuild doesn't help either

Comment: are you sure the button is not overlapped by another view?

Comment: @has19 I'll look into it. I don't think so but is there any way of verifying?

Comment: change getBaseContext() to getApplicationContext()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: I tapped on Main Page I'm able to see toast]

```
package com.example.vinaymaneti.button;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button b1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b1);

        b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Hello", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code is working perfectly. I have took all your code an placed and tried. It worked fine for me .

Comment: Maybe I haven't understood how guillotine menu works. You created the same activity and it worked but it didn't in my case. My main activity is creating a view of guillotine activity using layout inflator and i'm trying to do event handling on that. Probably that's why i'm going wrong. I'm posting my main class. could you please help?